# piezo to switch a transistor

Tags: arduino, piezo, toggle-switch

so my idea is to create a circuit that when the piezoeletric  is pushed, like a switch, but i wanted to make a variable so i can control how much force it needs to acionate the transistor[image: PCB out of paint]
so when something come in the piezo and knocks it it send a signal to the arduino

sorry my bad drawing, i just need to know the values and if this is wright

Comment: I’m voting to close this horribly stated question because it has been abandoned for years without the asker making any effort to clarify the problem or fix the numerous typos.

Answer (score 1):

The simplified circuit is:

[image]

V1 is piezo and output signal is on collector of Q1.

However, if you want to hold the pin on arduino high for a time, you need to add the capacitance to the gate or somewhere else. Or do it by software.

Edit:

A version with stay high for a time can be modified to this:

[image]

It will extend the 1ms pulse from piezo to 200ms. For different timing change the C1. D2 is gate protecting zener diode.

Answer (score 0):

If you are pushing or tapping a piezo element, that is a voltage generator.  At extremely low currents it can make several volts.  This might be enough to turn on a small MOSFET like a 2N7000 or 2N7002.  The transistor drain can then drive an Arduino input pin.

Comment: it would be like 3v on the piezo that would generate... just for you to get the idea of the project...
the piezo if knocked by a second i wanted to make that that voltage opens the gate of the transistor that is going 5 v from the bat... so the out pin of the transistor is the switch ir will work? like you said here? because it cant go any more than 2 v on the out of the arduino